# Compiler requirement for override and final

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, overriding, virtual, c++11

I can remember that during the discussion about general attributes which finally lead to the new contextual keywords `override` and `final` it was suggested that compiler support for these ore some **may be optional** (I guess it would read in the standard text as "behavior is implementation-specific). But I can not find any trace about this optionality in the FDIS and the corrections afterwards.

But since not finding it is not proof, I have to ask: **Is the support** as described in 2.11p2, 9.2 and 10.3 of the FDIS **for `override` and `final` obligatory for a conforming compiler?**

Is it for example required that a *conforming compiler* rejects

```
class Foo {
    void func() override; // Error: not virtual, 9.2p9
};
```

Or is it still conforming by ignoring *override*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's required that `override` is not ignored by a conforming implementation. First, `override` can only appear in the declaration of a virtual member function.

9.2/9:

> [...] A virt-specifier-seq shall appear only in the declaration of a virtual member function.

Second, a virtual function which doesn't override a member function of a base class but is marked `override` makes the program ill-formed.

10.3/7:

> If a virtual function is marked with the virt-specifier override and does not override a member function of a base class, the program is ill-formed.

As both are diagnosable rules of the standard it is illegal for a conforming compiler to ignore violations. (1.4/1)

The same reasoning applies to `final` and the relevant requirements are in 9 [class]/3 and 10.3 [class.virtual]/4.

Answer (score 5):

The *use* of `override` and `final` is optional for the programmer, but nowhere does it say that the compiler can ignore them.

This might have been different for the earlier proposals which used attributes instead of keywords. Attributes leave a lot more freedom to the compiler.

Comment: "optional for the programmer"... nicely put :-)